# "Magic" "class"

Tags: php, class

```
<?php class gdTemplateDB {
        [...]
     function rewrite_dependencies($section, $id) {
        global $wpdb, $table_prefix;
        /*var_dump($this);
        die;*/
        **include($this->plugin_path.'code/t2/templates.php');**
        [...]
      }
?>
```

I'm digging through the code of a wordpress plugin called GD star rating.
There are two "magical" things that I cannot figure out why:

1. The class above apparently has no parents, but when I var_dump the $this pointer, it turns out to be an instance of another class called GDStarRating, and GDStarRating also has no parents! And, you know that the $this pointer cannot be abitrarily reinstantiated. So I can't understand why the $this pointer behaves like that.
2. The function `rewrite_dependencies` is **statically** called from another class (`gdTemplateDB::rewrite_dependencies`, not `$instance->rewrite_dependencies`) called gdsrAdmFunc, and that class also doesn't have any parent-child relationships with GdStarRating. But it works just fine.

Please let me know, what can possibly cause those "magic" things?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class a{
  function aa(){
    var_dump($this);
  }
}

class b{
  function bb(){
    a::aa();
  }
}

$ob = new b();
$ob->bb();
```

here `a::aa()` outputs

```
object(b)#1 (0) {   // $this is instance of b
}
```

Here $this in class a is object of class b because,

function `aa` of class `a` is called from function `bb` class `b`.

function `bb` of class `b` is called from object of class `b`.

Answer (score 2):

For backwards compatibility reasons, PHP allows you to call non-static methods as static methods. When calling non-static methods in this way, it does **not** unset `$this`. Instead, the value from the other instance bleeds through into the new method.

You can duplicate this with the following code:

```
class A {
  function foo() {
    global $c;
    echo "In A: " . ($this === $c ? 'true' : 'false') . "\n";
  }
}

class B {
  function bar() {
    global $c;
    echo "In B: " . ($this === $c ? 'true' : 'false') . "\n";
    A::foo();
  }
}

class C {
  function baz() {
    global $c;
    echo "In C: " . ($this === $c ? 'true' : 'false') . "\n";
    B::bar();
  }
}

$c = new C();
$c->baz();
```

Which prints:

```
In C: true
In B: true
In A: true
```

However, if you mark static methods as such, then PHP behaves properly and `$this` is not defined. In this example, if you declare `A::foo()` as `static function foo()`, and `B::bar()` as `static function bar()`, you see this instead:

```
In C: true

Notice: Undefined variable: this in test.php on line 13
In B: false

Notice: Undefined variable: this in test.php on line 6
In A: false
```

Comment: How do I give half a point to an answer for half answering the questions? :)

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear enough, but this explains both questions. The $this pointer doesn't magically inherit from a class. You are just seeing the $this pointer from the other class bleeding into a different function.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'm wondering why the developers of that great plugin use this stupid way of coding :|

Answer (score 1):

is there some extract function call?
$this pointer **can** be abitrarily reinstantiated using this function :P

```
extract(array('this' => new stdClass));
var_dump($this); // object(stdClass)[1]
```

Comment: I see no **extract**, but anyway, thank you, that information is helpful for me :D